# Is GCC 4.5 still required to build biarch (Shared WoW64) Wine on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, gcc

I would like to build a [biarch Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/BuildingBiarchWineOnUbuntu) on my 64 bits laptop. But reading all the pages of the WineHQ project on such a configuration, I found [a page about gcc version](http://wiki.winehq.org/GccVersions) (written in May 2013), explaining that gcc version to be used, should be 4.5. Using Ubuntu 14.04, the gcc version I currently have is 4.8 ("known to not work" to build Wine, according to Wine pages). I tried to install gcc 4.5.3 on my laptop, but so far I haven't managed.

Should I persist in installing gcc 4.5, or is it now unnecessary? 4.8 would be OK?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I got an answer from a Wine developer. He said that it is gcc 4.8 **.0** which is an issue. gcc 4.8.2 is OK. So I used it to compile my biarch Wine, and indeed it's OK.